# Simple MYSQL Group By and Join

Tags: mysql, group-by

**Table** users

- id - Primary Key, AI
- username -    varchar (50)

**Table** logins

- login_time - DateTime
- member_id  - int (11)

**This SQL selects mid and max login_time and sorts DESC** 
SELECT member_id, max(login_time) as time FROM logins
GROUP BY member_id
ORDER BY time DESC

**Question** 
How do you select and join username onto member_id for each row?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT u.username, max(l.login_time) as time FROM logins l
LEFT JOIN users u ON (l.member_id = u.id)
GROUP BY l.member_id ORDER BY time DESC
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT l.member_id, max(l.login_time) as time, u.username FROM logins as l
join users as u on u.id = l.member_id
GROUP BY l.member_id ORDER BY l.time DESC
```

Comment: MYSQL throws an error for ORDER BY l.time. I prefer to write 'table t', rather than use the keyword 'as' which is generally used for column aliases.